# How to better combine preserved eggs with strong ammonia smell with other foods?

Tags: eggs, duck

How to better combine or use preserved duck eggs with strong ammonia smell with other foods? Specially if will get rid of or at least alleviate the strong ammonia smell.

Comment: Is such an odor expected, or is it an indication of spoilage?

Comment: As far as I know the ammonia smell is a byproduct of the preservation process: [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Century_egg)

Comment: Have you eaten eggs preserved with this technique before, and found their taste enjoyable?

Comment: I have not because of the pungent smell, and presumably taste. Perhaps a non-western user may shed light on how to enjoy them as they are considered a delicacy.

Comment: Certain pungent "delicacies" are often said to be an acquired taste. I think you may be facing a decision as to whether or not this is a taste you wish to acquire.